# How to fix fatal error in WordPress wp-settings.php

Tags: php, wordpress

Can some help me with fatal error in wp-settings.php file.

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function create_initial_taxonomies() in /home/admin/public_html/wp-settings.php:393 Stack trace: #0 /home/admin/public_html/wp-config.php(72): require_once() #1 /home/admin/public_html/wp-load.php(50): require_once('/home/admin/pub...') #2 /home/admin/public_html/wp-blog-header.php(13): require_once('/home/admin/pub...') #3 /home/admin/public_html/index.php(4): require('/home/admin/pub...') #4 {main} thrown in /home/admin/public_html/wp-settings.php on line 393

Answer (score 1):

It look like your WordPress core files are corrupted. I suggest downloading a new copy of WordPress, and replacing everything in your site's wp-admin and wp-includes directories with the corresponding files from the new WordPress download.